# how to get the server to talk to the client

Tags: javascript, client-server

I'm pretty new to web development, so excuse my ignorance.

What I'd like to know is if there's a way to have the server broadcast a message to clients. An example of this would be a client page that has a newsfeed, and every time a new story comes in to the server, the server sends that information out to the client and the client updates its page's newsfeed. I don't want the client to constantly be polling the server every few seconds, asking "hey, is there a new story now? what about now? what about now???" I want the client to be doing its own thing, and then be interrupted by a message from the server.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at WebSockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets

Comment: You can check "Comet programming" ...I was also looking for something similar to your request to build a chatting application, but I wasn't able to find a better solution.

Comment: Actually AJAX will not do this, but kind of opposite. The client will periodically request the server for new data and whenever server send the new data, it can display a message to the user. Here the server is not sending data to the client unless the client requests for it. But you can build newsfeed using AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For newer browsers, you can use [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets) to open a continuous connection to a server and then client/server can send each other messages whenever they want.

For older browsers, the way this is typically done is that the client has to "poll" the server to ask the server on some regular schedule if the server has any new messages for it.  The server usually cannot connect directly to the client because of firewalls, local security settings, unknown location, etc... so the client has to connect to the server.  Polling can either be of the regular variety, poll every 60 seconds with an ajax call to ask if there's anything new or it can be more of a long poll where the client asks if there is something new and, if there is something new, the server returns right away with that data.  But, there's nothing new, the server hangs onto the polling request for some time period waiting to see if there is something new.  Eventually, the server will either return that it has nothing or return with a new message if there is one.  When the client gets the response, it starts the "long poll" sequence over again.  [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) is an example of the "long poll" in a library form that makes it easier to implement.

Comment: Though it's a fairly new standard, websockets are probably the best option. AJAX would work, but their requests has a much bigger overhead. It depends how often the server needs to update the client.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney - I agree web sockets are better for this type of problem, but I don't see any version of IE that supports it so you're stuck with implementing something else for IE.

Comment: follow up: I've run across something called "jsonp" a couple times, where (as I very very basically understand it) an html tag asks for some script from some server after specifying a callback function, and the server fires back that callback function with some data as a parameter. So wouldn't it be possible for the server to instead sorta save the callback function and keep firing it back to the client whenever it wants to?

Comment: JSONP doesn't work that way.  JSONP is simply a form of javascript in the server response.  It does not allow the server to call the client like you are asking for.  It is typically used when the client is trying to solve a [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) issue and it doesn't offer any particularly unique capabilities of solving the problem asked about here.

Answer (score 0):

Pusher is tailor-made
http://pusher.com/